# Apache OpenNLP bug it doesn't load en-pos-maxent.bin

Tags: java, apache, opennlp

I'm trying to use Apache OpenNLP POSTagger example codes, and i've come up with an error, and below is the code

```
public String[] SentenceDetect(String qwe) throws IOException 
 {

POSModel model = new POSModelLoader().load(new File("/home/jebard/chabacano/Chabacano1/src/en-pos-maxent.bin"));
PerformanceMonitor perfMon = new PerformanceMonitor(System.err, "sent");
POSTaggerME tagger = new POSTaggerME(model);

String input = "Hi. How are you? This is Mike.";
ObjectStream<String> lineStream = new PlainTextByLineStream(
        new StringReader(input));
perfMon.start();
String line;
while ((line = lineStream.read()) != null) {

    String whitespaceTokenizerLine[] = WhitespaceTokenizer.INSTANCE
            .tokenize(line);
    String[] tags = tagger.tag(whitespaceTokenizerLine);

    POSSample sample = new POSSample(whitespaceTokenizerLine, tags);
    System.out.println(sample.toString());

    perfMon.incrementCounter();
}
perfMon.stopAndPrintFinalResult();
```

Error at this line

> .load(new File("/home/jebard/chabacano/Chabacano1/src/en-pos-maxent.bin")

The method load(java.io.File) in type ModelLoader  is not applicable for the arguments(org.apache.tomcat.jni.File)

Answer (score 1):

This is actually not a bug in OpenNLP. It's a bug in your code, as you load the class `File` from the package (aka namespace) `org.apache.tomcat.jni.File`.

Yet, the [API of OpenNLP](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/api/opennlp/tools/cmdline/postag/POSModelLoader.html) requests you to use the class `File` from the standard JDK package `java.io`, i.e. you should import [`java.io.File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) instead.

In general, this should fix your problem.

**Important hint**

You should migrate your code, as models should not be loaded via `POSModelLoader`

> Loads a POS Tagger Model for the command line tools.
>
> Note: Do not use this class, **internal use** only!

Instead you can use the constructor `POSModel(InputStream in)` to load your model file via an `InputStream` referencing the actual model file.

Moreover, the class `POSModelLoader` was only present in previous releases of OpenNLP (versions <= 1.5.x). In the latest OpenNLP version 1.6.0 it was removed completely. Instead you can and should now use the constructor of the [POSModel class](https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.6.0/apidocs/opennlp-tools/opennlp/tools/postag/POSModel.html) to load/initialize the model you need.

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem with XML parsing. Try this, it worked for me.

```
    System.setProperty("org.xml.sax.driver", "org.xmlpull.v1.sax2.Driver");
    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = 
        context.getAssets().openFd("en_pos_maxent.bin");
        FileInputStream inputStream = fileDescriptor.createInputStream();
        POSModel posModel = new POSModel(inputStream);
        posTaggerME = new POSTaggerME(posModel);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
```